# How to add items from a MenuStrip event to a ListBox using a For Next Loop

Tags: vb.net, listbox

That might have sounded weird so let me explain.

I have a school assignment that has me pulling my hair out. I have to get a collection of 5 facts and have them display to a ListBox using a For Next Loop. The user would use an InputBox to input the facts.

I dont know what to put in the For Next to fetch the string from the InputBox. I'm at my wits end and am falling behind.

Here is what I have so far

```
Public Class frmWWIIFacts

Private Property RemoveAt As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub AddFactToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddFactToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim intFact As Integer
    Dim strInputFact As String

    strInputFact = InputBox("Do you want to add a fact?", "Add a fact")

    For 

    Next
    strInputFact = InputBox("Do you want to add a fact?", "Add a fact")


End Sub

Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Application.Exit()

End Sub

Private Sub ClearListToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClearListToolStripMenuItem.Click

    lstFacts.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub RemoveFactToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RemoveFactToolStripMenuItem.Click



End Sub
```

I've submitted a reddit post requesting *some* assistance but its gotten me nowhere. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3t614u/vb2015_using_menustrip_to_addremove_items_in_a/

I would love some help on this. Please ask questions if your confused on my method or if you need to know more.

Comment: Does it have to be a MenuStrip and InputBox?  A plain textbox on the form could collect the data and a plain button could work in place of the menustripitem.  `For n As Integer = 1 to 5` satisfy the other part (one more button to add the TB fact to the lb)

Comment: @Plutonix On the assignment page it looks weird. The instructions tell me that I have to use a MenuStrip to activate an InputBox but in the picture, it looks more like a dialog box with no area to input text; just a box with a Yes/No choice. I do have to use a MenuStrip and InputBox. Its the stipulation.

Comment: Sounds like a MessageBox

Comment: @Plutonix I'll quote directly from the assignment page:

"For the “Add Facts” Menu Item
     Use a For Loop to prompt the user for five(5) facts about World War 2 
     Use an InputBox to get a fact (set to a string variable).
     Add the fact to the ListBox."

And here is the image of what I was talking about: http://152.46.13.240/MoodleContent/ComputerProgramming1/Unit11/Menus_InputBoxes_MessageBoxesAssignment.JPG

Comment: Is my answer on the right track or is Plutonix right that I misunderstood you?

Comment: The silly prompt is at odds with the use of a For/Next loop to enter 5 items - it lets the user abort early.  I'd use something like Josh's code but change the prompt (he doesnt exit the loop if they say no anyway)

Comment: @Josh It's really close but is there a way to have the InputBox not iterate continuously? Like stop after the user has entered a fact and to add another, they would have to click the MenuStrip event again for each iteration.

Comment: No, the loop is inside the click event - it will loop 5 times per click

Comment: Yes, but the way to do that is to delete the For/Next loop, which would go against the assignment. Are you sure that's the intended behavior?

Comment: @Josh thats my point: *asking* the user is at odds with both "enter 5 facts" and use a `For/Next` loop

Comment: @Plutonix I'm just assuming this assignment wasn't thought through to that level. Heaven knows I had plenty of idiotic assignments back in my VB6 class...

Comment: I agree.  I would just ignore that stupid MessageBox so you get the 5 and the loop and menustrip elements easily.  just change the prompt in the code given.  make the menu text "Enter 5 WW2 Facts"

Comment: @Plutonix and Josh I really couldnt thank you guys enough. No wonder I'm losing my mind, its literally impossible to do that. I really appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Comment: No, not impossible just goofy code and far too many pop ups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to do this:

```
Private Sub AddFactToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddFactToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim intFact As Integer
    Dim strInputFact As String

    lstFacts.Items.Clear()

    For intFact = 1 To 5
        strInputFact = InputBox("Please enter a fact:", "Add a fact")
        If Not strInputFact = "" Then
            lstFacts.Items.Add(strInputFact)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the problem is that the assignment is to "add 5 facts".  The OP ought not ask, instead prompt for `"Fact #" & i.ToString()`